# Why doesn't np.where() work here?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, where-clause, inequality

**The issue**

I have two large lat-lon arrays that appear to have the exact same values after a difference calculation loop I put them through, even though they shouldn't. To find out if there were any entries between the two arrays that weren't equal, I used an `np.where()` statement. However, the return doesn't seem to be giving me what I'm asking for. That is, it's giving me entries where the values ARE equal, exactly the opposite of what I asked for.

**The code**

First I created a small example to see how the function works...

```
test1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[2,4,6,8,10]])
test2 = np.array([[1,2,3,4,6],[1,4,6,8,9]])
print np.where(test1 != test2)
```

Output:

```
(array([0, 1, 1]), array([4, 0, 4]))
```

Okay, that makes sense. The entries at `[0,4]`, `[1,0]`, and `[1,4]` all have non-matching values. I then tried the same command on my arrays, which both have a size of `[120,192,288,40]`.

```
print np.where(array1 != array2)
```

Output:

```
(array([  0,   0,   0, ..., 119, 119, 119]), array([  0,   0,   0, ..., 191, 191, 191]), array([  0,   2,   2, ..., 287, 287, 287]), array([ 6,  0,  1, ..., 37, 38, 39]))
```

That's a lot of entries. I checked a couple entries, just the first and last, to see what the non-matching values were.

```
print array1[0,0,0,6], array2[0,0,0,6]
print array1[119,191,287,39], array2[119,191,287,39]
```

Output:

```
-0.0712321083736 -0.0712321083736
0.0709354614045 0.0709354614045
```

The entries `np.where()` gave me contain equal values for both arrays, even though I asked for entries where the values are NOT equal. I even checked an entry not included in `np.where`'s return to see if somehow it got confused.

```
print array1[0,0,0,5], array1[0,0,0,5]
```

Output:

```
0.0185121137892 0.0185121137892
```

Still equal. `np.where`'s not only giving me entries where the values are equal; it's giving me only some of those entries and ignoring others.

**The question**

Why did `np.where()` work for the test, but it doesn't seem to work for the actual data? Is it a problem with numpy, or my data?

Comment: Try `np.where(~np.isclose(array1 , array2))` to account for being floating pt values?

Comment: This returned no entries. Does the ~ mean finding where values between the two arrays are NOT close?

Comment: Floating-point rounding and imprecise input data mean that values that would be equal in exact arithmetic aren't always exactly equal in floating point math. Comparing floating-point values for exact equality is rarely the correct thing to do.

Comment: Basically `np.isclose()` replaces `==` and thus `~np.isclose()` replaces your `!=` but allows for some tolerance as is needed for most floating pt number comparisons.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Look like I have some arithmetic debugging to do...